# Swift optional binding still having null data

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have added some extra functionality to the Alamofire package in my project and for some reason on this optional binding it is going into the If statement whether the "error" key exists or not in the json. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(validData, options: options)

if let error = JSON["error"] {
    print(error!)
    return .ServerError(error as! String)
}
```

When there is no error the print fails with a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding `as? String` which would help the optional unwrap and not run inside the if statement if the string is not there:

```
let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(validData, options: options)

if let error = JSON["error"] as? String {
    print(error)
    return .ServerError(error)
}
```

Comment: The force unwrap is unnecessary.  Even if `JSON` is an optional, we're already in an `if let`, so why would we force unwrap?

Comment: This works the best given what I am doing, won't fail if JSON contains a JSON array, makes sense to try and unwrap to a string.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `JSONObjectWithData` returns `AnyObject`.
You have to cast the type to something suitable to get reliable results in this case a `Dictionary`

```
do {
    let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(validData, options: options) as! [String:AnyObject]

    if let error = JSON["error"] as? String {
        print(error)
        return .ServerError(error)
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Probably want *something* in the case that `JSON["error"]` can't be unwrapped as a `String` instead of a silent failure, but +1 either way.

Comment: Yeap this does do the trick but i forgot to mention that when there is no error it won't always be a dictionary of [String:AnyObject]. I have JSON arrays sent sometimes and this method fails on that

Comment: If you want to retrieve and check the error this way, the JSON object must be a dictionary, otherwise leave JSON as `AnyObject` and check (and cast) the type right after the deserialization.